# Basic AWS S3 PHP setup

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been trying for a while to setup just a basic PHP implementation of an upload form to upload to Amazon's S3 service, but I can't get anything to work.

Reading through their docs, their examples all seem different. **What is the correct way to provide credentials and upload a file?**

On their github repo, it says:

```
// Require the Composer autoloader.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate an Amazon S3 client.
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2'
]);

try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
        'Key'    => 'my-object',
        'Body'   => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

On http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html they say:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => '<profile in your aws credentials file>'
));

// Upload an object by streaming the contents of a file
// $pathToFile should be absolute path to a file on disk
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => 'data_from_file.txt',
    'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,
    'Metadata'   => array(
        'Foo' => 'abc',
        'Baz' => '123'
    )
));

// We can poll the object until it is accessible
$client->waitUntil('ObjectExists', array(
    'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
    'Key'    => 'data_from_file.txt'
));
```

Can anyone who has been able to do this recently shed some light on the setup here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I've always used this guide. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html  Also ensure you have the cURL extension installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key from the documentation you've linked to is this sentence:

*You can provide your credential profile like in the preceding example,
specify your access keys directly (via key and secret), or **you can 
choose to omit any credential information if you are using AWS 
Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for EC2 instances***

So if you're running this from an EC2 instance, you simple omit any mention of credentials, and it should pick up the permissions from the role associated with the instance.

If you're not running in AWS, you would need to create ~/.aws/config for the user running the code, and create a profile that looks something like

```
[profile profile_name]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
region = us-east-1
```

Then you'd just do:

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
  'profile' => 'profile_name'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it working by just using the embeded credentials

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");

require "./aws/aws-autoloader.php";

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret',
    ),
    "region" => "us-east-1",
    "version" => "latest"
));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Composer
Once PHP CLI is installed, download the Composer installer script with:

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

Compile Composer with PHP Version

`sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

check composer
`composer`

Install/download aws sdk library

`composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`

`php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php`

Sample Code Download File

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$bucket ="sentimentanalysis2021";
$key ="KEY";
$secret ="SecretKEY";
$region ="ap-south-1";
$location = "/var/www/html/openpbx/record/temp/";
// Establish connection with DreamObjects with an S3 client.
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => '2006-03-01',
    'region'      => $region,
    'endpoint'    => "https://s3.$region.amazonaws.com/",
        'credentials' => [
        'key'      => $key,
        'secret'   => $secret,
    ]
]); 
//var_dump($client);
//Download File
$file_s3 = null;
 $objects = $client->getPaginator('ListObjects', ['Bucket' => $bucket]);
    foreach ($objects as $listResponse) {
        $items = $listResponse->search("Contents[?ends_with(Key,'wav')]");
        foreach($items as $item) {
//            download($client,$item['Key'],$location);
        $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
             'Key'    => $item['Key'],
                'SaveAs' => $location.$item['Key']
        ));
        $file_s3 =$location.$item['Key'];


        }
 }

//Read Files
$objects = $client->listObjectsV2([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
]);
foreach ($objects['Contents'] as $object){
    echo "{$object['Key']}\t{$object['LastModified']}\n";
}

function download($client,$file,$location){
$client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $file,
    'SaveAs' => $location.$file
));
}

// Create Folder
 /* abc is the folder name */
$client->putObject(array( 
                   'Bucket' => $bucket,
                   'Key'    => "abc/",
                   'Body'   => "",
                   'ACL'    => 'public-read'
                  ));


$file_Path = '/amol/20220516141901_919033_9999.wav';
$key = basename($file_Path);
try{
    $result = $client->putObject([
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $key,
        'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
        'ACL'        => 'private',
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}




?>
```